# How to re-open the case within 2 days using Process builder or Apex class

Tags: trigger, process-builder

How to re-open the case within 2 days using Process builder or Apex class

Process Builder

Condition:

[EmailMessage].Parent.Status Equals Picklist Closed
[EmailMessage].Incoming Equals Boolean True
[EmailMessage].Parent.ClosedDate Greater than or equal Formula **[EmailMessage].CreatedDate < 2** -

**Error** - **The formula expression is invalid: Incorrect parameter type for operator '<'. Expected DateTime, received Number**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use process builder scheduler instead of formula.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V--CWh5eZlo

Answer (score 0):

Within the formula, it has to resolve to a DateTime, so try adding the days to the Created Date:

```
[EmailMessage].CreatedDate + 2
```